# Enter a description of the language accepted by following Deterministic Finite Automata

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

I try to minimize it but it didn't help so here is the DFA that tricks my mind:

[image: DFA]

here are some of the rejected strings but I didn't come up with a solution from that...

1,  00,  000,  001,  010,  100,  0000,  0001,  0010,  0100,  1000,  00000,  00001,  00010,  00100,  01000,  10000

Comment: You might consider posting this on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead.   The gang there is more computer sciencey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems like this, where the DFA has a lot of accepting states, it's often a good idea to reason about what strings the DFA **rejects** rather than what it accepts.

In this case, only states q2 and q4 reject, and the language described by rejections is more straightforward. To get to q2, you need `000*`. To get to q4, you need `000*10*` or `0100*` or `1000*`.

So the strings that are rejected are those have at least 2 `0`s, and at most one `1`.

Ergo, the strings that are accepted are those that have two or more `1`s or have at most one `0`. Note that this description covers the empty string and short strings like `1`, `0`, `01`, `10` and `11` (they all have at most one `0`).

Comment: Thank you for advice " it's often a good idea to reason about what strings the DFA rejects rather than what it accepts." it will save me a ton of time next time came across this type of DFA :)